# React Native Offline data to be updated?

Tags: react-native, redux

I am new to react native. I am making a app to support offline. So, I use asyncstorage and redux-persist package. Data is saving offline and data could clean every functions are working fine. So, my question is

**How can I detect offline data to be always updated. Could you mention your experience solutions to solve it.** I found more questions in google about saving data solution not including update solutions.

Below are what I think.

- push notification from Google cloud messaging ( It is ridiculous to let user know push notification on device screen to update data)
- Websocket might work on it.( I don't want to build for that in my backend server now)
- Saving each reducer store with datetime and check with app is online or offline. If online, it would request from server to get reducer in which  has new datetime, if so, I would update my offline data. I am not sure that could cover all. ( In this case, I would create all reducer name and updated datime when device request )

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want your app offline data updated with the online server data. You can use [react-native-offline](https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-offline). You can check its doc. When app open it sync can sync data with the server and update. So you app will always update.